# how to submit a form from frontend and show values in the grid at backend magento panel?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, magento-1.5, magento

i am again posting this question as i was unable to do what i wanted to, and also didn't get the answer of my previous question. Hope, this time it will catch the eye of someone who can answer.

I have created a module which enables to submit a form in the backend just like news module and faqs module etc and shows the result in the grid.

But what i want now is that i must be able to save the form frontend and show the results in grid.

i was told that it can be done through indexcontroller.php of my module. So what i actually did was i copied the save action of adminhtml controller and try to use it in index controller.

```
public function postAction() {
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {


                $model = Mage::getModel('events/events');       
                $model->setData($data)
                    ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));

                try {
                    if ($model->getCreatedTime == NULL || $model->getUpdateTime() == NULL) {
                        $model->setCreatedTime(now())
                            ->setUpdateTime(now());
                    } else {
                        $model->setUpdateTime(now());
                    }   

                    $model->save();
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('events')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setFormData(false);

                    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                        $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId()));
                        return;
                    }
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                    return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setFormData($data);
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            return;
        }
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('events')->__('Unable to find item to save'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }

    /* testing */
```

and in frontend i created a phtml file :

```
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>


<form  action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl(); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="events_form">

    <div class="fieldset">

        <ul class="form-list">
            <li>
                <label for="title"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('events')->__('Title:') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input style="font-size:14px;" name="title" id="content" value="" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" size="29"/>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="wide">
                <label for="content" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('events')->__('Description:') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <textarea name="content" id="content" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('events')->__('Description') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" style="font-size:14px;" name="overview" cols="55" rows="30"></textarea>
                </div>
            </li>


        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <p class="required"><?php echo Mage::helper('events')->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('events')->__('Submit') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('events')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>

</form>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var eventsForm = new VarienForm('events_form', true);
    //]]>
    </script>
```

But no luck :( can anyone please tell me how to get it done.

Comment: What do you mean "no luck :(" ? We need to see a debug message. Is the data being saved in your database? If so, your adminhtml needs to be updated to show it. If not, your model isn't saving it correctly and we can start from there.

Comment: No data isn't saved in the DB :( not even the successful save message or Unable to save message appears up

Comment: We definitely need a debug message to help out. In your catch{} block, use Mage::log($e->getMessage()); and make sure logging is enabled. Then navigate to your system log in /var/log/. If nothing shows up, try more debugging on your save handler and get an error of some sort to be returned.